# Explain polarization in RF in which the conductor is stationary

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, polarization

Consider a metal rod parallel to $x$-axis moving with velocity $\vec v =(0,v,0)$ perpendicular to magnetic field $\vec B=(0,0,B)$.

[image]

Lorentz force will give rise to the electric field $\vec E = - \vec v \times \vec B$, so the rod becomes polarized.

Now, how to explain this force in a reference frame, in which the rod is stationary? Is such a reference frame, the field should be $\vec E = 0$, no? And then, how to explain the polarization in this RF?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say that $\vec{E}=0$ in the frame moving with the rod?

Comment: @garyp I think $\vec v = 0$ in this frame, the rod doesn't move... But the force will be Lorentz transformed somehow...?

Comment: You must consider what a moving magnetic field looks like, and you've just found one of the arguments why moving magnetic fields look like electric fields (and vice versa).

Comment: [Lorentz Tranformation of EM Fields](http://%5Blink%5D(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think it is discussed in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_magnet_and_conductor_problem)